# Resize issue in Windows form application in 2560x1600 resolution display

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have a form application working fine on various displays with varying screen resolution but in a machine with 2560x1600 resolution it shrinks to a very small size.

It works fine all smaller resolution and i am not able to find a reason behind it. I have used anchor, docking, autoscalemode and various other properties still it fails only in this above mentioned screen resolution

Comment: pl post your code here

Comment: The most obvious explanation is that it works just fine.  But that it looks tiny on such a high resolution display.  Most owners of such a display will change the DPI scaling to at least 150% to ensure programs remain usable.  You could also screw up by declaring your app dpiAware, like you should, but then hard-code pixels in your code, like you should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the window on startup, for example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom / 2);
}
```

That's the example only. You have to modify the above code to ensure you are finding the right screen and the right coordinantes.